# MVVM Async UIImage loading from network on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, mvvm, rx-swift

I have been using MVC since my first app on iOS... now i want to try MVVM.

My approach is that a Model can contain the remote URL and the ViewModel makes the request to download the image. (pushing then to binded view)... I think this is suitable so as to avoid making a network request in Views (or even worse, cells!)

```swift
class Person: NSObject {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var avatarURL: URL?
}
```

```swift
class PersonEntryViewModel {
    var name:String?
    var avatarImage:UIImage?

    init(person: Person?) {
        super.init()
        // omitted: binding self.name based on person.firstName & person.lastName
        var request: URLRequest? = nil
        if let avatarURL = person?.avatarURL {
            request = URLRequest(url: avatarURL)
        }
        fetchImageFromNetwork({ response, data in
            if let data = data {
                avatarImage = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

What do you think?

My doubts are about memory. I could have a big array of viewmodels filled with UIImages...

Comment: About the memory.. Use a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` to avoid the pressure from downloading. :)

Comment: `fetchImageFromNetwork` makes everything on background and just calls the closure on main

Comment: I do not think the memory is a problem then. Another tip is so use `NSCache()` on your images to avoid loading each time. But imo this looks great. :)

Comment: images can get bigger and bigger... think about a photo album

Comment: That would still reduce the loading time if you cache them. I assume the images are in a database storage?

Comment: no, they are downloaded from network

Comment: Like from a URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209796/discussion-between-fabiosoft-and-putte).

Comment: yes, take a look to `avatarURL`

Comment: I don't see why you have the rx-swift tag on this question. I don't see any Rx code in here at all.

Comment: @DanielT. i was thinking to implement observables on images (and other properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each cell is holding its own `PersonEntryViewModel` and that is getting discarded in the cell's prepare for reuse, then memory isn't a problem because images will be discarded at the same time.

I think it would be best not to put the download code in the init method. Better would be to have some sort of trigger method you can call when the view model is passed to the cell.

It really depends on what the larger architecture looks like.

If you want to see some examples of handling images in an Rx-MVVM-C app there are a couple of great ones in the RxSwift slack channel:

https://rxswift.slack.com/archives/CTSAM9V27/p1583148003073800
https://rxswift.slack.com/archives/CTSAM9V27/p1583149698079500

Join the discussion by going here: https://rxslack.herokuapp.com

Comment: Ok so you suggest to not store the UIImage inside the view model but call a method from the cell and trigger the download with a completion closure. But the network request code should be in view model anyway. Right?

Comment: You can store (cache) the image in the view model if you want. That way you don't have to download them again when the user scrolls back, but then (as you pointed out yourself) you could run out of memory. You will need some way to limit the total number of images cached in order to be sure to avoid memory overload. There are lots of different caching strategies, it depends on your use case.